# Inner join within Dynamic SQL is not working

Tags: t-sql, inner-join, dynamic-sql

I have a query within a SP like below

```
declare @Sql nvarchar(max);

SET @Sql= N'   select a.ultimatedunsnumber,a.account,a.AccountSubSegment 
               into #channel_shift 
               from #temp_p06 a inner join #temp_p02 b            
               on a.ultimatedunsnumber=b.UltimateDunsNumber
               and a.accountchannel<>b.accountchannel ';
 print @sql     

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql;
```

And the `#temp_06` and `#temp_02` tables are created dynamically within the SP and they got created successfully.

But the above query is throwing an error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 66 An expression of non-boolean type
>   specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ultimate'.

Comment: I guess you are not passing the real assembling of the dynamic T-SQL statement, because there is no point in having such static statement executed like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment .Actually the tables used in the from clause is created from an argument that is passed into the stored procedure .I am passing the old tablename and new tablename as parameters and the procedure tends to find out the differences between both the tables .This is one of the temp tables used in there .

Comment: Could you post the exact print message?

Comment: There's no point of posting code that doesn't produce the problem. The code you've posted will not generate this error. Please post the actual code (feel free to change the names) or at least some code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: `Line 66` here as it is less shown

Comment: Sorry for the late reply .my print statement is as follows

Comment: select distinct a.ultimatedunsnumber,a.account,a.AccountSubSegment 
         into #channel_shift 
         from #temp_p06 a inner join #temp_p02 b            
       on a.ultimat
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 66
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ultimat'.

Comment: it seems the query text is not complete. It is truncated. Are you sure you are using nvarchar(max) to store the text? if you read the error message the join 'a.ultimatedunsnumber' has been truncated to  'a.ultimat'. It means everything after 'edunsnumber' has be droped and doesnt run.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this MEdwin.yes I have now posted the entire procedure in the code snippet above .the variable is declared as nvarchar(max)

Comment: print @sql should give you the full query text if you are using nvarchar(max) to store. There should not be any reason to truncate at all.

Comment: @Aparna Show me exactly how you are performing the concatenation!

Comment: Thanks MEdwin for pointing this out .I have indeed declared the variable as nvarchar(max).But for some reason when I reached the bottom of the sql statments it is not executing .I declared one more variable and parsed that sql statement within this variable the procedure completed successfully .not sure why the entire sql statements could nt be executed in one variable declared as nvarchar(max)